# Receive mock location in FusedLocation

Tags: android

I set mock location, but I can't receive any location when mock mode is enabled, normally I receive last location and update location every 3sec - when mock mode is disable - but with mock mode enable I cant get any

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Utils.printDebug("onConnected");

    Location mockLocation = new Location("network");
    mockLocation.setLatitude(50.120089);
    mockLocation.setLongitude(18.993206);
    mockLocation.setAccuracy(4.0f);
    mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockMode(mGoogleApiClient, true);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockLocation(mGoogleApiClient, mockLocation);

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);

    if(mLastLocation!=null)
        Utils.showToast(getApplicationContext(), "Last know location is " + mLastLocation.getLatitude() + ", " + mLastLocation.getLongitude());

    startLocationUpdates();
}
```

I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />` and developer option for mock location enable.

How can I receive that mock location?

Answer (score 6):

First off, to be able to set and use mock location, you need to have a debug manifest:

> src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

with the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
```

and run you application in debug mode.

Secondly, you need to enable Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION. Do this on the device, Settings -> Developer Settings -> Allow Mock Locations

Then you have two choices, either let your Activity implement

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
```

Or use a

```
PendingIntent
```

as a Location handler.

Assuming you implement

```
 GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
 GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

connect to the LocationServices in your onConnected(Bundle bundle) callback

**Example using LocationListener:**

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockMode(mGoogleClient, true);
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
            .setFastestInterval(5000L)
            .setInterval(10000L);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleClient, locationRequest, this);

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Location changed!" + location.toString());
}
```

**If you want to use a PendingIntent, replace "this" with the intent:***

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, LocationHandler.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleClient, locationRequest, pendingIntent);
```

The LocationHandler extends IntentService:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    final Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
    Log.d(TAG, "Got Location: " + location);

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction(TAG);
    broadcastIntent.putExtra(LOC_PARCEL, location);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
```

**Setting a mocked location**

Now, you can set a mocked location:

```
    Location location = new Location("MockedLocation");
    // Time is needed to create a valid Location
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTimeNanos = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
    location.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(elapsedTimeNanos);
    location.setTime(currentTime);
    location.setLatitude(latitude);
    location.setLongitude(longitude);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockLocation(mGoogleClient, location);
```

Here is how one could implement a mocked location that is moving:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Location loc = route.getNextLocation();
            if(loc != null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockLocation(mGoogleClient, location);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 5000);
```

Comment: Great answer! One little update: `ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION` is deprecated in API level 23 [source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION)